# Probability with marbles and no replacements

Tags: probability

Two marbles are drawn randomly one after the other without replacement from a jar that contains 4 red marbles, 4 white marbles, and 7 yellow marbles. Find the probability of the following events:
(a) A red marble is drawn first followed by a white marble.
(b) A white marble is drawn first followed by a white marble.
(c) A yellow marble is not drawn at all.

---

I understand how to do this with replacements but don't understand how to adapt the formula to no replacements

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please explain what you have tried.

Comment: I am lost. I understand how to do this with replacements but don't understand how to adapt the formula to no replacements

Comment: Without replacements, the # of marbles available for the 2nd draw would be 14 instead of 15.  That is the difference between no replacements and replacements.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was so much easier to understand than that book!

Comment: Your welcome.  When thinking about simple probability, think in terms of # of good outcomes divided by total number of outcomes.  I tried to answer this question as simply as I could so you could understand it easily.

Comment: yes, that is the exact answer question they asked. The wording is so bad in this class it makes things terrible!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

red marble drawn first is $4/15$, white marble drawn next is $4/14$ so

a) $4/15$ * $4/14$ = $16/210$ = $8/105$

white marble drawn first is $4/15$, white marble drawn next is $3/14$ so

b) $4/15$ * $3/14$ = $12/210$ = $6/105$ = $2/35$

no yellow marble drawn is $8/15$ * $7/14$

c) = $8/15$ * $7/14$ = $56/210$ = $28/105$ = $4/15$